# Why my second ObservableCollection is getting update?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, observablecollection, treeviewitem

I have **two** ObservableCollections filled with Items (that Items are also ObservableCollecions filled with other types of object) of the same type.

**_TreeViewBase** - First ObservableCollection is 'base' with all data.

**_TVData** - Second ObservableCollection should store only 'needed' items, I have also TreeView with ItemSource binded to TVData.

Function **FillAliasTreeView** is used only to fill _TreeViewBase with data so I will not paste code here.

When at the begining of program I **assign** _TreeViewBase to _TVData in **LoadSideBar()** function everything is ok.
Both of ObservableCollection are storing all data.

But when I search something ( and my TVData is modified in **SearchBox_TextChanged()** ) then It's seems that
also _TreeViewBase is modified.

How it is possible? Did I made some major mistake in my code?

My class ( almost full code ) :

```
public partial class SideBar : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ConnectionModel> _TreeViewBase;
    private ObservableCollection<ConnectionModel> _TVData ;



    public SideBar()
    {
        TreeViewBase = new ObservableCollection<ConnectionModel>( ConnectionUtilities.LoadObservableConnections() ) ;
        TVData       = new ObservableCollection<ConnectionModel>();

        InitializeComponent();


        DataContext = this;

        var loadSideBar = Task.Factory.StartNew( async () => { await LoadSideBar();   } );
        loadSideBar.Wait();

        OnPropertyChanged("TVData");
    }


    public async Task LoadSideBar()
    {
        // this function is used to fill my _TreeViewBase  
        await FillAliasTreeView();

        TVData = TreeViewBase;
        OnPropertyChanged("TVData");

    }

     private async void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string newsearchText = SearchBox.Text;

        if ( (newsearchText == "" || newsearchText == "Search..." || newsearchText.Length < 3  )  ) 
        {

            TVData.Clear();
            TVData = null;

            MessageBox.Show( (TVData == null).ToString() + " " + TreeViewBase.Count.ToString());


            TVData = new ObservableCollection<ConnectionModel>( TreeViewBase );

            AliasTree.ItemsSource = TVData ;

            AliasTree.UpdateLayout();

            return;
        }

        searchText = SearchBox.Text;


        if (TVData != null)
        {
            await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
            () =>
            {
                foreach (ConnectionModel cm in TVData.ToList<ConnectionModel>())
                {
                    foreach (SchemaModel sm in cm.schemas.ToList<SchemaModel>())
                    {
                        foreach (SchemaCollection sc in sm.schema_collections.ToList<SchemaCollection>())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                ObservableCollection<TableModel> octm = (ObservableCollection<TableModel>)sc.collection;

                                for (int i = 0; i < octm.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    if (!(sc.collection as ObservableCollection<TableModel>)[i].TABLE_NAME.Contains(searchText))
                                    {
                                        (sc.collection as ObservableCollection<TableModel>).RemoveAt(i);
                                        i = i - 1;
                                    }
                                    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync( () => OnPropertyChanged("tables") ) ;
                                }
                                Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => OnPropertyChanged("collection") );
                            }
                            catch (Exception exc) { }
                        }
                        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => OnPropertyChanged("schemas") );
                    }
                    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => OnPropertyChanged("TVData"));
                }
                Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => OnPropertyChanged("TVData"));
            });

            await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => ExpandAll(AliasTree));
        }
    }


    private void ExpandAll( ItemsControl root )
    {
        if ( root != null )
        {
            foreach (var subItem in root.Items)
            {
                if (subItem != null)
                {
                    ExpandAll( (TreeViewItem)root.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(subItem) );
                    try
                    {
                        if (((TreeViewItem)root.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(subItem) as TreeViewItem) != null )
                            ((TreeViewItem)root.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(subItem) as TreeViewItem).IsExpanded = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc) { };
                }
            }

            AliasTree.UpdateLayout();
        }
    }
```

Thank You for any suggestions.

Comment: You are setting one equal to the other: TVData = TreeViewBase; which makes them the same observable collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your constructor, you set `TVData` and `TreeViewBase` to two different instances of `ObservableCollection<>`. But then this line:

```
TVData = TreeViewBase;
```

makes them refer to the *same* instance. The old `TVData` observable collection is discarded, and both of those variables now refer to the same observable collection.

This is just [how reference types work](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html).

Comment: Thank You.

Is there any clean solution to assign data from TreeViewBase to TVData?

Comment: @Wiktor: Unfortunately, observable collections do not have an `AddRange` method, which is what you would ordinarily use. Since this is only done once during initialization, you can create a *new* observable collection that copies all the items from the other one: `TVData = new ObservableCollection<ConnectionModel>(TreeViewBase);`